# How to write jQuery overscroll code correctly for div saving when page refreshes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Azoff's Overscroll jQuery plugin: [WATCH IT HERE](http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll)

And I wrote this code, but it seems not to be working:

```
var PlanetRefreshTimeSec = 1; // Planet refresh time in seconds..

    function loadData() {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });

        var updateScrollPosition = function() {
            var div = $('#show_planet_realtime');
            div.scrollTop(div.height());
        };

        $("#show_planet_realtime").load("../in/GameEngine/RealTimeRender.php?p=<?php echo $player; ?>", updateScrollPosition, function () {
            setTimeout( function () {
                loadData();
            }, PlanetRefreshTimeSec * 1000);
        });
    }
    $( function () {
        loadData();
    });
```

I want to keep the map position, while this map is automatically refreshing content with `.load()`. I heard it's done with the jQuery cookie plugin, so I tried it too:

```
$(function(o){
    o = $("#my_planet").overscroll({
        cancelOn: '.no-drag',
        scrollLeft: 200,
        scrollTop: 100,
        drag: function () {
            var cookie_value = JSON.stringify($(this).offset());
            $.cookie('newPosition', cookie_value, {
                expires: 7
            });
        }
    }).on('overscroll:dragstart overscroll:dragend overscroll:driftstart overscroll:driftend', function(event){
        console.log(event.type);
    });

    if ($.cookie('newPosition')) {
        //console.log($.cookie('newPosition'))
        $("#my_planet").offset({
            top: JSON.parse($.cookie('newPosition')).top,
            left: JSON.parse($.cookie('newPosition')).left
        })
    }
});
```

But it's not working though... Like I said before, I have the exact [Azoff's Overscroll](http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll) jQuery map, and I want to save its position, while refreshing the whole page or that map is refreshing its content...

Answer (score 0):

This might be a timing/racing issue - you're trying to get the height of the div while it's empty. Consider delaying the start of the scrollTop function call. Maybe try replacing `div.scrollTop(div.height());` with `setTimeout(function(){div.scrollTop(div.height())},200);`.

Comment: thanks for respond, but i tried it, no luck :( it seems your code wrong :( my whole div doesnt load.

Comment: Does the div load if you don't change that line?

Comment: Your code, I think is good, i just copied wrong :) I think problem is in this line `$("#show_planet_realtime").load("../in/GameEngine/RealTimeRender.php?p=<?php echo $player; ?>", updateScrollPosition, function () {`